# Turtlebot2 Rviz 2d_pose_estimation and 2d_nav_goal don't work

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, turtlebot2, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a remote computer to control my real turtlebot2.

When I  `roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch` and I drag the `2d_Pose_Estimate` button arrow on the map, nothing happens.

I have checked `<fixed_frame>`, it's the map, I have checked the `/initialpose`, and I get information when I use the pose estimate button but the turtlebot2 does not move at all.
I check my `rostopic list` and I see `/initialpose` there and everything. I don't get it.

Could I be missing some udev rule thing on my remote PC?

My turtlebot2 uses a Kinect camera as sensor, `2d_Pose_Estimate` works on the`ros_master_uri` laptop the turtlebot2 is physically connected to.

I can see that I am publishing to the `/initialpose` on the terminal, but the robot still does not move in Rviz.

In the laptop physically connected to the turtlebot2, I have `ROS_MASTER_URI` and `ROS_IP` set to the IP of the robot. On the other Remote PC I have `ROS_MASTER_URI` set to the IP of the robot, and `ROS_IP` set to the IP of the remote PC. Did I do it wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404947/turtlebot2-rviz-2d_pose_estimation-and-2d_nav_goal-don%27t-work/) by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2022-08-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-08-24**:
Can you add in the edit a picture from the `rqt_graph` of your nodes and their connections? Can you ping IP addresses both ways (`robot <--> remote PC`)? Does standard check talker/listener works for you?

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-08-31**:
@ljaniec When I switch the camera to realsense, it works now for some reason. I had another question about path planning for turtlebot2. Is there some topic that telle you that a plan cant be generated? I have a fuller explanaition of my question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/405788/turtlebot3-goal-cannot-be-reached/)

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-09-05**:
I think you should post this as an answer, because this is some way to solve this problem :)

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-09-20**:
@ljaniec I need help with another turtlebot2 question, my remote PC cannot connect with ROS Master for some reason. Please check it [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/406218/remote-pc-cannot-connect-to-ros-master/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I switch the camera to realsense, it works now for some reason. I had another question about path planning for turtlebot2. Don't know why

---

Originally posted by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) with karma: 167 on 2022-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0